# How to make universal framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, swift3, build-settings

I have created one project **(Project 1)** in which I am creating one framework which I want to use in different project **(project 2)** just like any other framework (drag drop in project).

**My Issue**

But when I created framework (in project 1) keeping device selected in xcode  when I use this framework in my project 2 it works only for device not for simulator.
vice versa if I created framework in project 1 keeping simulator selected in xcode and use this framework in project 2 it only works for simulator the.

errors for this is

[image]

**What I am trying to achieve**

My framework created from project 1 should run on both device and simulator in project 2.

following are my settings in both the projects

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Xcode will build the framework according to the target selected. If framework built for simulator, architecture will be X86_64,i386, on the other hand for device it will be armv7, arm64. 
Can check the architecture of the framework using lipo command as below.

```
lipo -info sample.frameowrk/sample
```

Now , in your case you want your framework should support both simulator and device. So, you need to combine both framework (built for device and simulator) and create a FAT framework using lipo command as below:

```
lipo <path to framework build for simulator>/simulator.framework <path to framework build for device>/device.framework -create -output universal.framework
```

Resulted universal framework will support both platform. You can check the architecture supported by the universal framework as below:

```
lipo -info universal.framework/universal 

output : arm64,armv7,x86_64,i386
```

Comment: Hi Harish, What do you mean by file1 and file 2 here? is this framework name if so why two different name for one framework? should I run this command from product folder?

Comment: This sounds like the correct approach, I have done this before as well, but forgot about it. I think he means compile the project for the simulator and for device and get both the output frameworks from those, then run the command above where file1 = simulator framework, file2 = device framework etc. you can run the command anywhere where both the framework files exist, just rename them so the one doesnt get overridden when compiling the second one.

Comment: I am getting error like /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't create temporary output file: OcrSdk.framework/OcrSdk.lipo (No such file or directory) .  why I am not able to create output?

Comment: @sss i have modified the answer for better understanding. Idea is to build the framework for both (simulator and device) and combining them to create a universal framework which will have a support for both simulator and device. Can you post the complete command you are trying to execute ?